# I am making a roll the dice game but my code isn't working

Tags: python

when after rolling number 1 comes out then I want the following text to be displayed: You rolled a 1

If any other number comes out I want to see the following text:
Its not number 1

this is my code:

```
import random

def roll (sides=6):
    num_rolled = random.randint(1,sides)
    return num_rolled

def main():
    sides = 6
    rolling = True
    while rolling:
        roll_again = input("Ready to roll? ENTER=Roll. Q=QUIT. ")
        if roll_again.lower() != "q":
            num_rolled = roll(sides)
            if num_rolled == "1"
             print("You rolled a", num_rolled)
        else:
            print("its not number 1")
        else:
            rolling = False


    print ("Thanks for playing.")

main()
```

But it isn't working I am getting the following message: invalid syntax

Can anybody help me please.

Comment: Surely the error message is more descriptive than that?

Comment: You have 2 `else` blocks, which isn't allowed in Python.

Comment: invalid syntax will appear with a reference to the line that it is indicating.

Comment: nope its just saying invalid syntax

Comment: do you have a suggestion how to change my code?

Comment: @PeterOchoa, just tested it myself and you **do** get a line number and hint (e.g. `File "test.py", line 17`) before the error message. If you run it in IDLE, the line will be highlighted in red.

Comment: @PeterOchoa What do you want to achieve with the two `else`s?! If `roll_again.lower()` is `q`, one thing happens, if it's not another thing happens. What's the third case?

Comment: I figured it out! the first `else` is indented wrong!

Comment: @MooingRawr Ohhh thanks but how to fix it?

Comment: @MooingRawr I am very new to python

Comment: indent it to where you want it to be..... python's indentation is super important. If you want your else to be with a certain `if` block line it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things incorrect with your syntax, please refer to my comments in this snippet of your code:

```
while rolling:
    roll_again = input("Ready to roll? ENTER=Roll. Q=QUIT. ")
    if roll_again.lower() != "q":
        num_rolled = roll(sides)
        if num_rolled == "1" #1
         print("You rolled a", num_rolled) #2
    else: #3
        print("its not number 1") #4
    else:
        rolling = False
```

1. missing a colon `:` at end of if statement.
2. line not indented like the rest (which are 4 spaces)*.
3. this line is not indented the same amount as its (apparent) corresponding if statement.
4. see comment 2.

I highly recommend you review your understanding of [indentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) which is super-critical in Python.
I'm sure you'll succeed soon!

* <sub>Technically speaking this is not a syntax error, but I chose to mention it since it's reflective of the other mistakes that broke the code.</sub>

Comment: @PeterOchoa you're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your syntax error.  I also noticed another fundamental mistake in the code: your `roll()` function returns an **integer** type object (for example `2`), but your if statement tests for a **string** type object (for example `"2"` or `"foo"`). These are two different things, logically speaking `2`!=`"2"`.

Comment: Issue number 2 isn't technically a syntax error (but you're right to point it out because it is a big style problem and a sign that the OP doesn't really understand indentation yet) since Python will accept it. Also, this solution still won't run because you haven't addressed the greater issue of 2 `else` blocks.

Comment: @Aurora0001 thanks for the comment, I tested it and you are right. I have added a note about it in the original answer.

Comment: @maze88 Thanks, for helping me!